# Calculating the planets and moons based on Newtons's gravitational force

Tags: orbit, mathematics, calculation, ephemeris

I am trying to understand how to calculate the orbits of solar system bodies in an n-body framework, based on the pair-wise gravitational interaction between the objects. At present, I am considering 44 objects (sun, planets, major moons and major asteroids).

I am starting with the state vectors (position and velocity) of each of the objects with Sun as centre obtained from `telnet ssd.jpl.nasa.gov 6775` (JPL Horizons) 01-Jan-2017 at 00:00 UTC and would like to let the system evolve for 4344h,  01-July-2017 at 00:00h.

I have written a program to do this in Java, and so far the results do not seem to be even reasonably close to what they should be, comparing with the state vectors obtained from Horizons. After every 2 second time step the net gravitational forces on each body from all of the others is calculated, and then in one shot all the velocities and positions are updated based on the accelerations from those net forces. Then I compare the final updated position vectors from the application with data obtained from Horizons after correcting for the Sun's updated position.

The comparison shows that the positions of Earth and the outer planets are have position error of less than 50km (In fact, the farther planets it is less then 10km). Where as for Mercury the error is 250km. And the moons of Jupiter and Saturn are off by 50,000 to 300,000 km!

In my application, I am not differentiating between the Sun, planets and moons, so I am not sure why there should be so much more error for the moons. I have tried decreasing the step size, from 2 seconds down to 0.25 seconds, but there is not significant improvement.

What might be the problems that I should investigate here? Are there things that clearly need improvement right away? Or perhaps there are tests I can to do help diagagnose the primary sources of error?

---

**EDIT:** Here is the gist of the calculation method *as requested in comments:*

```
while (nowT < endT) {
    doOneStep(step, nowT)
    nowT += stepT
}
```

`allItemLinks` is collections of `ItemLink` - links between objects. in this case Gravity link between all object pairs. For `n` objects, there will be `n.(n+1)/2` links

```
doOneStep(double deltaT, double nowT){
    initForces fo all items to 0,0,0
    for each ItemLink **allItemLinks**)
        inf.evalForce(deltaT, false)
    updatePosAndVel(deltaT, nowT, true)
}
```

In ItemLink:

```
evalForce(double deltaT, boolean bFinal) {
    addGravityEffect(deltaT);
}

boolean addGravityEffect(double deltaT) {
    rVector = item2.pos - item1.pos
    double gF = G.mq.m2/r2
    fVector = gF in rVector direction
    item1.addForce(fVector)
    similarly for item2 to item1
}
```

`allItems` is a collection of Item objects (Sun, planets and moons)

```
void updatePosAndVel(double deltaT, double nowT) {
    for each Item of **allItems** updatePandV(deltaT, nowT);
}
```

In Item:

`netForce, nowAcc, effectiveAcc, deltaV, newPos etc.` are all Vector3d

```
updatePAndV(double deltaT, double nowT, boolean bFinal){
        nowAcc = netForce / mass
        effectiveAcc = mean of lastAcc and nowAcc
        deltaV = effectiveAcc * deltaT
        meanV ...
        newPos = oldPos + meanV * deltaT
}
```

Not working on gravitation fields but with direct forces due to inter-object gravity.

With the above code, I am able to get stable orbits. Even the orbit times of the moons are good. Get nice Saturn set with the Cycloidal motions of moons and the Uranus set with helical motion of the moons around Uranus. 
I do not know as to how to send files or images for this discussion

Comment: The offset of Mercury would be about right, due to relativistic effects. I'd blame the inaccuracy of the moons positions on numerical accuracy errors, especially that they interact with each other a lot.

Comment: Also, if you calculate their position relative to the Sun yo For Io, you have semi-major axis of 0.003 AU orbital radius, at distance of 5.2 AU from the Sun. This works poorly with floating point values as the fixed, large offset from center of the system of coordinates prevents them to increase precision by changing the mantisse and changes occur at the far tail of the base with a lot of precision lost behind its tail.

Comment: This is more a CS problem. Which precision are you using? Have you considered Runge-Kutta and/or symplectic integrators? What you are having here is the n-body problem. The error for mercury is likely due to relativistic effects.

Comment: I don't think Mercury being off by 250 km in seven days has anything to do with relativity, or the moons of Jupiter by 100,000 km either. The moons have the worst error because they have the shortest period and so the most change. My guess is you are just using $\mathbf{v}_{i+1}=\mathbf{v}_i+\Delta t \ \mathbf{F}/m$; $\mathbf{x}_{i+1}=\mathbf{x}_i+\Delta t \ \mathbf{v}_i$ and nothing more, but we won't know until you share more. If you want to write it by yourself and don't want to use a library solver, RK4 or RK4(5) are only about two dozen lines or so.

Comment: Calculation duration in 6 months (01 Jan 2017 to 01 July 2017).

Comment: I am coding in Java with Vector3d ('double' variables). Suspecting precision problem, tried with Big Decimal(32 significant digits) for positions of Europa of Jupiter (only one object with BigDecimal since it takes too long to calculate). Still the error for Europa was very large similar to earlier calculation with 'double'.  I am not using any integration methods - just numerical additions, updating positions and velocity every 2 seconds.

Comment: What numbers are you using for mass (or mass parameters)? You may also want to read https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2416/where-can-i-find-a-set-of-data-of-the-initial-conditions-of-our-solar-system/13491#13491

Comment: If you're not using *at the very least* a simple RK4 integrator, then you will always get completely wrong answers. It's not precision, it's not relativity, you're just using the [Euler Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) which *being only 1st order*, by itself will not even give you anything close to a physically correct orbit. Just take a look at the first image in the Wikipedia article https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfAv5.png Until you post some equations or lines of code *into the body of your question*, I can't really post a complete answer, but 1st order is worthless here.

Comment: [**RK4**, aka **The** Runge-Kutta method.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#The_Runge.E2.80.93Kutta_method). Or perhaps see http://graphics.cs.ucdavis.edu/~joy/ecs277/other-notes/Numerical-Methods-for-Particle-Tracing-in-Vector-Fields.pdf or see http://vmm.math.uci.edu/ODEandCM/PDF_Files/Appendices/AppendixH.pdf or try http://vmm.math.uci.edu/ODEandCM/PDF_Files/ChapterFirstPages/First38PagesOFChapter5.pdf .

Comment: Or your can just look at [How to solve ODEs with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22356166/3904031). This shows the use of the Dopri853 algorithm (a higher order, interpolating, adaptive step size RK) from the [Apache Commons ODE solver](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/ode.html) for planets in java. Pay attention to the answer also!

Comment: @uhoh     Thanks for moving my additional data to the main question.

Comment: @uhoh sorry, there is misunderstanding. What I meant was that I do get orbits since you mentioned that the orbits may not close back. Frankly, I was thrilled when I saw the cycloidal and helical motions and I over-expressed myself.  It appears that the basic approach may be correct for the planets but has problem when handling the moons and looking as to whether any special handling is required when near massive objects. I appreciate your very active an useful response. I do need help for this.

Comment: OK no problem! I've started deleting some of the old comments. I think this is a really nice question! I'll try to post an answer in a day or two, and probably others will also. You need to use a higher order integration than the 1st order Euler method you're describing, I'll try to give you at least two options.

Comment: @SF. looks like you are right! Turning on General Relativity is necessary to fix Mercury. There is a cyclic runout during each orbit of a few hundred km. I misunderstood the integration time (thought it was seven days) but over months, it's necessary. Will post the GR results as soon as I can make a pretty plot and get the math into MathJax.

Comment: @uhoh I am back. I modified my code for RK4. ie for each object is re-positioned with RK4 method. During RK4 method for for a particular object all other objects are maintained at the previous-step locations. Comparing results (after 6 months from 20170101) with Horizons, I find that the error are very high with 100s step, lesser with 10s step. Even with 2s step, the errors are Earth 30km, Jupiter 17km, Outer plants less tha 3km. But Venus 50, Mercury 240, Europa 120000, Io 330000 etc.
Any comments. Is it with Relativistic effect or gravity effect with time delay at light speed

Comment: @vishu the correct way to do multi-body propagation is to construct one single vector *with all position and velocity variables*. So (as I mentioned in my answer) if there were two bodies, you'd use $ y=(x_1, y_1, z_1, x_2, y_2, z_2, v_{x1}, v_{y1}, v_{z1}, v_{x2}, v_{y2}, v_{z2})$ which is `X` in my python script, for $n$ bodies the vector will have length $6n$. All variables are advanced in parallel in each of the fours sub-steps of each iteration of the RK integration. Also I would hold off on Jupiter's moons until you add higher order gravitational multiples (e.g. $J_2$) due to oblateness.

Comment: I didn't understand  'higher order gravitational multiples (e.g. J2)'

Comment: @uhoh back again with all variables advanced in parallel for each sub-step of RK4. Now I find consistent error wrt Horizon's after 6 months from 20170101 00:0. What I mean is that the error for planets and major moons still exist, but nearly remain the same with 10s, 100s, 600s or even with 1800s calculation steps. But with 1800s, Phobos-Mars starts running away from Mars. It appears 1800s too large step for Phobos with very short orbital period. My conclusion, RK4 has allowed increased step time (say 600s), but still errors remain, due to some reasons other than the calculation step.

Comment: @vishu ok that's great news! Check that you are using the best values for standard gravitational parameters ($G$ times $M$), JPLs latest numbers can be found [in this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22948/12102). After that, there are two big corrections to simple point-mass to point-mass Newtonian gravity that I can think of; 1. *General Relativity (GR)*, and 2. higher-order *gravitational multipoles* (e.g. $J_2$ and beyond) and tidal forces. Mercury will show a big improvement with GR, and the Earth-Moon and moons of giant planets will show improvement with non-point gravity.

Comment: @vishu check your masses, and I'll update/add an answer for the GR part and something to address $J_2$. Give me a day or so.

Comment: The GM values are all taken from sd.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/xfr/gm_Horizons.pck. Thanks. I will wait, no hurry.

Comment: Error frommy side it is ftp to  'ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/xfr/gm_Horizons.pck'

Answer (score 7):

Aside from numerical issues, "With Sun as centre" may be part of your problem. Get all the data from Horizons relative to the Solar System Barycenter, not the Sun, which moves relative to the barycenter. That barycenter is an inertial frame of reference, whereas the center of the Sun is not. Also make sure that you are putting in the initial position and velocity of the Sun and letting it move, if you aren't already.

Comment: Good point! I didn't even notice that.

Comment: I am taking data from horizons with Sun-centre at 20170101 and let the objects react and move. Initially position and velocity of Sun are both 000. During calculation The sun does move. After completing the calculations till 20170701, all the resultant data are modified back with respect to the new position and velocity of the Sun as base. This is then compared with data from Horizons for 20170701 again with Sun-centre.

Comment: What I am recommending is that you get all of your data relative to the Solar System Barycenter (@0). _Not_ the Sun (@10). If you do it correctly, the Sun will _not_ have an initial position and velocity of zero. Then you don't need to rebase to the new Sun position and velocity at the end.

Comment: But is it not that Barycenter itself is dependant on the relative positions of the planet. I can understand that Earth-Moon Barycenter is fixed relative to Earth and Moon. But with multiple planets dodn't it change with planets' postions.

Comment: No. That's the whole point of finding and using the barycenter. It is the center of mass of all of the solar system bodies, and so by conservation of momentum, it does not move in the inertial frame of a closed solar system, regardless of how the bodies in the solar system move.

Comment: @mark Thanks. Let me digest that first ( conservation of momentum and hence the center does not move - of course considering isolated solar system) . I will try with data with Solar System barycenter. It will(might) improve the accuracy of the planets, but the large error for the smaller moons ... I seem to have some other problem. Will come back

Comment: @mark I ran the calculations with g@0 data from Horizons and compared end results with g@0 data at end date. The error values are exactly same as before. One main advantage is that I do not have to adjust the end positions and velocities to recenter with new sun position for result comparison with g@10 data at end date. For error of small-moons, I am playing with my understanding of gravity propagation time and time dilation :) . Let me see ..

Comment: You are likely having numerical issues or parameter issues with the moons. The motion of the moons should be integrated relative to the bodies they are orbiting, treating other bodies as perturbations. Relative to their distance from the Sun, the moons are moving tiny amounts about their parent body. Also you need to have accurate GMs for all the bodies. (You can usually find that sort of data in the Horizons output headers.)

Comment: The GM values are all taken from ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/xfr/gm_Horizons.pck.

Comment: @MarkAdler How to simulate the motion of the Sun? Newtonian gravity by other planets?

Answer (score 2):

I'll post the numerical methods in this answer, and the full-blown solar system calculation (including relativity and possible effects from the Sun's oblate shape) as a second answer. There's just too much to put it all in one answer.

The method you describe using looks like the [Euler Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) or what can be called [Euler Forward method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerForwardMethod.html). At each time step $dt$ you calculate all of the forces and their resulting net accelerations $\mathbf{a}$, and then just increment the velocities $\mathbf{v}$ by $\mathbf{a} dt$ and all positions $\mathbf{x}$ by $\mathbf{v} dt$. You need absurdly tiny time steps to get even close with this. You mentioned 2 seconds and 250 milliseconds, a bit short for solar system timescales.

In the script below, I've written the Euler Forward method and two more [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) low order methods usually called RK2 and RK4. For each method a simplified (fake) Mercury orbit around a fixed Sun is calculated for 100 days, with the number of iterations varied from 10 to 10,000. Also, for each, I use the [SciPy](https://scipy.org/) library solver `odeint()` with a relative precision tolerance of 1E-12 per step. [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) is a python wrapper for `lsoda` from the FORTRAN library `odepack`.

You can see that even RK4 agrees with `odeint` *to the level of meters after 100 days* if you use a time step of about 15 minutes, and the Euler Forward method (what you use) will need an absurd number of steps to even approach this.

Numerical techniques are not the only issue here, I will post a second answer in a few days with the rest of what you need. *I may do it under a separate question rather than post two answers to the same question*.

But this should get you started either coding RK4 in java, or looking for a java numerical library like the Apache one mentioned in comments.

The simplest standard way to solve an orbital problem using an ODE solver is to put all of the cartesian coordinates and velocities in one long vector, call it $y$, and write a single function for the time derivative:

$$\dot{y} = f(t, y)$$

So if you had two bodies and three dimensions, the vector $y$ would be:

$$ y=(x_1, y_1, z_1, x_2, y_2, z_2, v_{x1}, v_{y1}, v_{z1}, v_{x2}, v_{y2}, v_{z2})$$

having six elements per body. The derivative of $x_1$ is $v_{x1}$, and the derivative of $v_{x1}$ is the acceleration $a_{x1}$ due to all of the other bodies.

Say you have one body in a central force with a standard gravitational parameter $GM$. The rate of change of position is just the velocity,

$$\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = \mathbf{v}$$

and the rate of change of velocity is the acceleration, due to the force;

$$\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} = \mathbf{a} = -GM \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^3}$$

If you had multiple bodies, the $\mathbf{r}$ would be the distance between pairs of bodies and for each body you would sum over all of the others as you've described already.

So if you wrote out $f$, it would be:

$$ f=(v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z}, -GMx/r^3, -GMy/r^3, -GMz/r^3).$$

The **Euler Forward method** that I believe you are using just iterates

$$y_{i+1} = h \ f(t, y_i) $$

with time steps of $h$. The improved **RK2 method** (shown below) would be written:

$$k_1 = f(t, y_i)$$
$$k_2 = f(t+\frac{h}{2}, y_i+\frac{h}{2}k_1)$$
$$y_{i+1} = y_n + h k_2 $$

and the ubiquitous **RK4 method** is written as

$$k_1 = f(t, y_i)$$
$$k_2 = f(t+\frac{h}{2}, y_i+\frac{h}{2}k_1)$$
$$k_3 = f(t+\frac{h}{2}, y_i+\frac{h}{2}k_2)$$
$$k_4 = f(t+h, y_i+k_3)$$

$$y_{i+1} = y_n + h (k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4)/6 $$

Here is the section that shows the similarity and differences between the Euler Forward method (the simplest Runge-Kutta method) and two higher order RK methods. This is written for clarity, not speed obviously.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
def deriv(t, X):

    x, v = X.reshape(2, -1)
    acc  = -GMs * x * ((x**2).sum())**-1.5

    return np.hstack((v, acc))

def derivv(X, t):
    return deriv(t, X) # historical reasons

def RK_all(F, t0, X0, n, h, method=None):

    hov2, hov6   = h/2.0, h/6.0
    t, X         = t0, X0
    answer, time = [], []

    answer.append(X)
    time.append(t)

    for i in range(n):
        k1 = F(t,        X            )
        k2 = F(t + hov2, X + hov2 * k1)
        k3 = F(t + hov2, X + hov2 * k2)
        k4 = F(t + h,    X + h    * k3)

        if   method == 'EulerFwd':
            X = X + h*k1        # X + h*F(t, X)

        elif method == 'RK2':
            X = X + h*k2

        elif method == 'RK4':
            X = X + hov6*(k1 + 2.*(k2+k3) + k4)

        else:
            pass

        t += h

        answer.append(X)
        time.append(t)

    return np.array(time), np.array(answer)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint as ODEint

GMs = 1.327E+20 # approx

X0 = np.array([-2.094E+10,  4.303E+10,  5.412E+09,
               -5.328E+04, -2.011E+04,  3.243E+03]) # approx

methodnames = ['RK4', 'RK2', 'EulerFwd']
niterations = [10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000]

Time = 100*24*3600.  # total time

methdict = dict()

for methodname in methodnames:

    times, answers, ODEanswers, posdevs = [], [], [], []

    for n in niterations:

        h  = Time/float(n)
        t0 = 0.0

        time, answer    = RK_all(deriv, t0, X0, n, h, method=methodname)
        # recalculate using library ODE solver for same times, to compare
        ODEanswer, info = ODEint(derivv, X0, time,
                                 rtol=1E-12, full_output=True)
        posdev = np.sqrt((((answer - ODEanswer)[:,:3])**2).sum(axis=1))


        times.append(time)
        answers.append(answer)
        ODEanswers.append(ODEanswer)
        posdevs.append(posdev)

    methdict[methodname] = (times, answers, ODEanswers, posdevs)

if 1 == 1:
    plt.figure()
    for i, meth in enumerate(methodnames):
        plt.subplot(1, 3, i+1)
        for time, answer, ODEanswer, posdev in zip(*methdict[meth]):
            x, y, z = answer.T[:3]
            plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.ylim(-2.8E+11, 0.8E+11)
        plt.xlim(-1.2E+11, 0.8E+11)
        plt.title(meth, fontsize=16)
        plt.plot([0],[0], 'ok')
    plt.show()

if 1 == 1:
    plt.figure()
    for i, meth in enumerate(methodnames):
        plt.subplot(1, 3, i+1)
        for time, answer, ODEanswer, posdev in zip(*methdict[meth]):
            plt.plot(time/(24*3600.), posdev)
        plt.yscale('log')
        plt.ylim(1E-01, 1E+12)
        plt.title(meth+' vs odeint', fontsize=16)
    plt.suptitle('RKmethod - odeint (meters) vs time (days)', fontsize=18)
    plt.xticks([0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: @vishu I will keep adding to this, if something isn't clear please leave a mesasge. It is good practice for me to write this all out - sometimes *explaining clearly* can be a challenge. **Anybody Else** please comments and suggested improvements on clarity are welcome!

Comment: @vishu is this looking at all helpful? Adding General Relativity to $f$ will correct the problem with Mercury and it's just a few more lines of code actually - I'll try to add it somehow in the next day or so. But to get everything working you need to either implement something like this or use a standard ODE solver in Java. Please feel free to add comments, or ask me to rewrite this or add more if it helps.

Comment: Now I have fairly good understanding what you are saying (learning Python as a side effect :) ). I will try out with RK4  after 25th September, since I will not abel tuse my laptop for the next 10 days.

Comment: @vishu OK that's really great! Running python the way I show here is very very slow, you would not normally do it this way, but it's an easy way to "prototype". If you use an integration library like `scipy.odeint` or 'scipy.ode` it's better.

Comment: I was taking average acceleration with the previous step, instead with the next future step would have been similar to Modified Euler. With the small increment time (2s and 250 ms) should have partly offset the inaccuracy, but looks like not enough for the orbits with higher curvature of the moons, which I understood from your explanations. Thanks for that.  I will try out with RK4  after 25th September

Comment: @vishu Take your time; with any luck, the solar system will still be around then :-)

Comment: @vishu so I've thought about it and decided that my existing answer really answers the question that you've asked. I've explained how to calculate "the planets and moons based on Newtons's gravitational force." Adding general relativity and higher order gravity terms beyond monopole is not covered by your question. I've written this as a [**new answer**](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23409/12102) to a [**new question**](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23408/12102) and linked it back here. If you agree that this answer (here) answers this question, you can consider accepting it.

Comment: @vishu but if you have questions about GR or other terms, I think it's about time you ask a new question. We should also do some housework and gather information thats in all of these comments into the question and answer, and then clean up the comments. The moderators have been kind to allow us to work like this, but we should tidy up a bit.